# AJAX/Rest only returning 100 items instead of full list

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, ajax, sharepoint-on-prem

On an onchange event on a select box (filtered lookup column where the value is the item ID) i make an AJAX call to auto fill certain fields on a form.

This works great except for it only returns 100 items (currently the list is pushing 200 items) and as such often a person will select an item for it then to do nothing. I am new to AJAX/REST and can not tell what I need to change.

Code:

```
  var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                         "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Traveller Details')/items";
    // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            //loop
            var i = 0;

            $.each(data.d.results, function (index) {
                var e = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl45_g_c16cce21_47f1_40fc_ab50_f38e7df1b86c_ff931_ctl00_Lookup");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

                i++; //Counter i used to find out that it is exactly 100

                //If account found
                if ($(this).attr('ID') == strUser) {
                   //Sets field attributes here.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OData provider for the REST API is configured to limit the number of items in a response to 100. It protects against developers inadvertently making a request that returns large result sets.

If there are more items the response will contain a continuation. In a JSON response the continuation will be a property named __next.

You can use $top if you want to override this behavior and have a large result set to be returned.

```
var url = appUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Order Details')/Items";  

var message = jQuery("#message");
message.text("");
getItems();  

function getItems() {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        message.append(String.format("Retrieved {0} items",
            data.d.results.length));
        message.append("<br/>");

        if (data.d.__next) {
            url = data.d.__next;
            getItems();
        }
    });
    call.fail(failHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this does explain a lot. I am not implementing this in this specific case as I found a way to filter by ID (since I am only interested in getting 1 item with a known ID). Code: $filter=(ID eq 215)

Comment: You can also set top to some number greater than 100 to retrieve more items in the initial call. I think that values can go as high as 1000, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @Roland If you're looking for a specific item, then `/Items(id)` should be your endpoint.  No need to filter for it.